# How to select the closest points of two selections? (same mesh)

Tags: python, vertices, selection-tools, select

Trying to find a way to select only the closest points to each other of two different selections in a joined mesh (image below)

Select only the closest points of A and B selection?

My goal is to measure the distance between A and B of a scanned object (dense mesh)

[image]

Comment: I wrote a script that I think may help you, but is incorrect. The reason it's incorrect is because I don't know how to distinguish two separate selections of points for the same mesh object. If A and B were two separate mesh objects, things would be easy. Since your points are separated by a relatively large distance, I could possibly distinguish the selection by their position. However, this method is very case specific and I don't know if it's generalized enough for you. Would that work?